# Replacing tags inside the parent tag using DOM PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

Here is what I got:

```
<div id="list">
<ol>
  <li>Ordered list 1</li>
  <li>Ordered list 2</li>
  <ul><li>Unordered list inside ol ul</li></ul>
  <ol><li>Ordered list inside ol ol</li></ol>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>Unordered list</li>
  <ol><li>Ordered list inside ul</li></ol>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>Ordered list 1</li>
  <ol><li>Ordered list inside ol ol</li></ol>
</ol>
</div>
```

I need somehow replace LI tags only inside div id="list" -> OL tags
I need so that it replaces only LI tags only within the first OL tags and not UL or the once inside OL -> OL tags

I tried using preg_replace_callback but it only replaces all LI tags inside id="list" and from what i figured it will be over my head to limit replacement only with first ol tags and not the rest, so I been suggested to try out PHP DOM since it should be as easy as div id="list" -> OL

I would appreciate if someone got me started with the code, maybe with something as replacing all LI tags with in the first OL tag within the whole content.

Comment: There are plenty of DOM tutorials to get you started. Read them first. Then come back with specific problems you encounter when using it. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp

Comment: @webbiedave [Please don't recommend w3schools...](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't do this with regex. It's a very bad way to parse (HT|X)ML. Use a genuine parser instead.  Here's an example using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class and the related [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/domxpath):

```
<?php

$doc = new DomDocument(); 
$doc->loadXML('your HTML');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);  

// get li elements in the first ol in the div whose id is list
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="list"]/ol[1]/li');

// change li elements to <li class='list'><div class='inline'>#####</div></li>
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('class', 'list');
    $number = $node->firstChild;
    $div = $doc->createElement('div');
    $div->setAttribute('class', 'inline');
    $div->appendChild($number);
    $node->appendChild($div);
}

// get the new HTML
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

NB also that you'll need to fix your `ol` and `ul` closing tags, which are currently unclosed.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned with want I wanted it to be replaced with I want LI tags to be replaced with <li class='list'><div class='inline'><num></div>

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to replace LI tags with <li class='list'><div class='inline'><num></div>, that is the content between LI tags must stay the same and not be replaced. If you added those changes to the code I would appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: I am getting "Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 72" and can't change anything that is in the $body content, I read somewhere that $doc->loadHTML("$body"); can be used instead since it is less strict, but for some reason I can't get it to work with out errors either. Here is the $body content http://pastebin.com/wBubk2LW and here is so far what i tried http://pastebin.com/W1XppsqD , if I comment out line 12 to 15 it seems to replace li tags, but i need commented tags too.

Comment: Here what i was thinking, replace <li> tag with <li class='list'><div class='inline'><num></div> , content of li tag must be after <num></div> tags (and in the code above content is placed instead of <num>), As for why I need <num> tag is that i was thinking later on to replace <num> with incrementation i++ through preg_replace, but i think it can be also done through this PHP DOM code, so instead of <num> I need incremented numbers. I really really appreciate all the work you already done.

Comment: @user The trouble is that your code does not have one XML root node. An easy way around this would be to wrap your code in a tag: `$doc->loadXML('<outer>' . 'your HTML' . '</outer>')`. Note that there are no `id="list"` elements in your code...

Comment: @user If you want this detail, it would be useful if you could pastebin some sample input and output code.

Comment: This is how the original output of the $body looks like http://pastebin.com/1TSA6fLp and this is how it looks with PHP DOM code http://pastebin.com/3QvQpcFL and this is how the PHP DOM looks like now http://pastebin.com/4KyXwXxq I change id="list" to class="steps" in the php dom code too.

Comment: @lonesomeday are you willing to help out?